# Copying files away from HFS+?

Tags: macos, rsync

I own two old hard drives, which are formatted as HFS+. Since HFS+ stores files in a hidden directory, if they are referenced in multiple places, I was wondering what the most efficient way to migrate the data away from HFS+ is. I have access to a Mac (for now). Can I still use rsync for this so I can benefit from things like resuming the copy? Or do I have to use the Finder so HFS+ is interpreted correctly?

I'm sorry for the broad question, but I tried to read through a dozens of questions here and I'm afraid to mess something up and only notice it down the road.

Comment: I presume you mean HFS+. What are the drives? Regular data drives or Time Machine? What type of files, just 'data' or specialist structures such as Photos Libraries, Logic projects? What do you intend to copy them to?

Comment: You are right, I meant HFS+. I got one drive with a Time Machine backup and another one which was just a data drive. There are no special structures involved. I own a NAS which is formatted as Btrfs, which I would like to put the data on. However, if this is more complicated I'm fine with any filesystem type.

Comment: idk how you'll fare with btrfs, I've no experience with it, however, you should have little trouble with flat files. Anything containing Apple proprietary structures like Photos libraries will likely break. The TM drive, on the other hand is only copiable by Finder & only to another HFS+. Nothing else can cope with the hardlinks.

Comment: Does that mean that even if I copy things from the TM drive using the Finder to any other filesystem type, I will most likely not copy everything correctly? I expected Finder to "resolve" (I'm not sure if this is the right verb) the links HFS+ uses internally so I end up copying the actual files again. If that's not the case for the TM drive, is this at least how it works for a "normal" HFS+ drive?

Comment: For a regular drive there really won't be many hardlinks, so I doubt there's anything to worry about. Finder knows how to follow them correctly, most other apps don't, so when it comes to copying a TM drive, any other copier will try to follow every one of half a million hardlinks & copy 'real' data for each. It may actually succeed, but you end up with 10TB instead of 1TB. It can't even be done now for APFS drives, only HFS+ could do this. idk what will happen trying to copy to btrfs, as Mac can't read that natively - presumably you'll be copying via whatever OS that's running under.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks a lot for your input!