# Rescuing data from HFS+ backup?

Tags: linux, mac, backup, filesystems

I recently learned about the "pitfalls" of using HFS+ when backing up data. I backed up a Time Machine drive a couple of months ago. I just used `rsync` to do so. So now I have a copy of it on my NAS, which uses Btrfs. How screwed am I? I didn't have the time to inspect the data in detail yet. The snapshots Time Machine created stored in `Backups.backupdb/username/<timestamp>` all seem to be multiple Gigabytes in size. The `. HFS+ Private Directory Data` directory is around 70 gigabytes big.

1. Did I already lose data by copying the files to a file system type other than Btrfs?
2. What do I do with the `. HFS+ Private Directory Data` directory? Is it useless?
3. Could I copy all files back to a drive formatted as HFS+ and then use the finder to back up the files correctly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copying files away from HFS+?](https://superuser.com/questions/1827054/copying-files-away-from-hfs)

Comment: Partially, but it describes another situation of mine. The question you linked is about a Time Machine drive, which is still only HFS+ partition. The one I'm talking about here isn't anymore, hence I want to double-check what my options are and not lose data to any misunderstandings on my side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time Machine makes extensive use of "hard links", where a file's data is stored only once on the disk, but the file appears in more than one path (or under more than one name). All of the hardlinks to the file are equally valid; none is more "real" or "official" than any other. This is a great way to save space on the disk if you need the same file to appear in more than one place, like when the same unmodified file needs to show up in multiple different hourly snapshots saved by Time Machine. HFS+ and APFS are not the only filesystems that support hardlinks, but they also support hardlinked *directories*, which other hardlink-capable filesystems don't always support.

Hardlinks are thus very different from the more common "symbolic links" (symlinks), which are a special kind of pseudo-files that just serve as pointers to some other path that contains the "real" file.

When you copy hardlinked files using tools that aren't hardlink-aware, or onto filesystems that don't support hardlinks, the space-saving nature of the hardlink arrangement won't be preserved, so all the data in those files will be copied multiple times; once for each hardlink to the file.

So if your non-hardlink-aware copy completed successfully without running out of disk space, every Time Machine snapshot it contains could be its own **entire copy** of the disk you were copying, instead of just containing a few files that changed plus a lot of space-saving hardlinks to all the files that didn't change since the previous snapshot.

So you probably didn't lose data, you probably just massively multiplied your copies of your data, wasting tons of space on the drive you copied it to. Now every snapshot is not just a small "delta" or "diff" showing what changed; every snapshot is now a full disk backup of what the disk contained at the time the snapshot was taken.

There's probably no easy way to take this super-bloated mega-copy of your Time Machine backup directory and convert things back into hardlinks to save space again.

Comment: Hard-linked files are widely supported, and `rsync` will preserve them if you use the `-H` or `--hard-links` option. The problem is hard-linked *directories*, which I don't think anything other than HFS+ supports, and Time Machine makes extensive use of (when backing up to HFS+).

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to write such a detailed response, @Spiff. This is a great relief! I'm fine with having a super-bloated mega-copy, I can manage that somehow. I much prefer it over a surprisingly-smallish partial-copy. I didn't know about the `-H` flag, thanks for mentioning it, @Gordon Davisson.

Comment: I think I made a mistake while copying files away from the `HFS+` partition. If I go into my backup of the Time Machine drive and inspect the contents of a snapshot of the home directory, I can find some directories showing up as binaries ("Unix Executable File") with zero KB. I can't access them. This is applicable to a lot of files in a lot of those snapshots. Is this just how a `HFS+` file system looks like if you copy it to a different file system?

Comment: Can I extract those files from the `.HFS+ Private Directory Data`, or should I just call it a day and give up? I'm not sure if there's anything worth saving in the first place to be honest.